# Get runtime ColdFusion syntax trees?

Tags: coldfusion, metaprogramming, coldfusion-11

Is it possible to get access to / modify ColdFusion syntax trees at run time?

I'd wager not, and a 10 minute google search didn't find anything. Fiddling with closures and writing metadata dumps, we can see stringified versions of objects like `[runtime expression]`, for example in the following:

```
function x(a=b+1) {}
WriteDump(getMetaData(x).parameters[1]["default"]);
```

Does it allow us to go no deeper than this, or perhaps someone knows how to keep digging and start walking trees?

Comment: Probably not without using internal classes. What's the use case?

Comment: You could dig around in the Lucee codebase: https://github.com/lucee/Lucee. Lucee is the open source CFML engine, and my personal preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default UDF parameter expressions aren't available in function metadata as you've found. Other libraries that have implemented some form of CFML parser are

**CFLint** (written in Java and using ANTLR)

https://github.com/cflint/CFLint

**CFFormat** (also uses a binary compiled from Rust)

https://www.forgebox.io/view/commandbox-cfformat

**Function LineNums** (pure CFML)

https://www.forgebox.io/view/funclinenums

Comment: Thanks, CFLint and its dependency CFParser look promising.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a function callStackGet() docs: https://cfdocs.org/callstackget which might be useful to whatever you are trying to do.

And another CFML parser (written in CFML) here: https://github.com/foundeo/cfmlparser